# Should we de[create-function]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

The [create-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/create-function) tag seems unhelpful at best, despite the 95 questions tagged with it. For one, it has no usage guidance and is mostly used to ask about creating a function. The most common questions have to do with PHP's now-deprecated `create_function`, but there seem to be better tags for those kind of questions (and [PHP deprecated it for a reason](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php)). The second-most common questions ask about SQL's CREATE FUNCTION queries in various implementations.

It passes all the [criteria for burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination/324071#324071):

- It is *not* unambiguous and rarely describes the content of questions in a helpful way
- It is much too broad to be on-topic, in the same way that a tag such as [write-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/write-code) would be too broad
- It does *not* add any meaningful information to the post
- It does *not* mean the same thing in all common contexts

Should we burninate [create-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/create-function)? Or is it not worth the effort?

Comment: It appears to be the actual name of a function. The fact that something has been deprecated doesn't mean that it won't be asked about, and certainly doesn't mean that we shouldn't have a tag for it. There's nothing inherently "too broad" about questions about a particular function. Your analogy to a [[tag:write-code]] tag makes no sense to me. The tag doesn't mean that someone is asking for a function to be created/written for them.

Comment: @CodyGray would it make more sense to re-tag all the questions in which someone is asking for help writing a function?

Comment: That's... not what the tag means.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I was offering to go through those questions currently tagged with [tag:create-function] and re-tag those that *don't* refer to PHP's version, to remove the ambiguity. I'd be happy with that, and would add tag info letting users know that's its expected use case

Comment: _It passes all the criteria for burnination_ ---> _It is not unambiguous_. So then how does it pass all the criteria for burnination?

Comment: @10Repsaysgetvaccinated because one of the criteria for burninating is that it be ambiguous; I use the double negative here to negate the burninate question of "is is unambiguous"

Comment: I honestly don't understand why this request was downvoted. Everything about [tag:create-function] is bad and it should not exist. Meta really disappoints me sometimes.

Answer (score 8):

Okay, the consensus seems to be that [create-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/create-function) is a useful tag but simply misused (-5 score on the proposal, but +8 on my comment proposing cleanup). In a day or so, I'll go through and make those edits, documenting them here. But I do want to make this an official proposal so that it can be properly up-and-down voted, rather than assessing based on the number of upvotes on the comment alone.

**Upvote** this answer to show support for cleaning up the [create-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/create-function) by removing this tag from questions that aren't about PHP's `create-function` function and adding some guidance.

**Downvote** this answer to argue for another method or no action necessary (comment below additional methods or solutions)

Comment: I think this is reasonable: we definitely don't want any questions tagged [[tag:create-function]] because they are requesting that someone write a function for them. But it looks like there is also a SQL operator `CREATE FUNCTION`. Perhaps that should keep the tag as well?

Comment: I propose renaming this to [tag:sql-create-function].